# How do you switch between two texts in one jQuery call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

Let's say you have a `.click()` call. What code could you write inside of that `.click()` call so that each time you click the selected element, you change the text between two strings. I'm assuming `.toggle()` and `.text()` would play a role here...

Comment: what two strings?  what are texts?

Comment: I don't think what the actual strings are matters....

Comment: Oh, nevermind.. I just figured out what you meant.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#someElement').toggle(function(){
   $(this).text('text1');
  }, 
 function(){
   $(this).text('text2');
 }
);
```

Comment: As you can see here, the toggle event can take several handler http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: This was deprecated in jquery 1.8 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: This should not be used as @vroo noted.

Comment: @hoopyfrood's answer is better

Answer (score 26):

Try something along these lines:

```
$element.bind('click', function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html() == 'string1' ? 'string2' : 'string1');
});
```

---

*Edit - 2020-01-28*

Note that `bind()` is now deprecated. You should be using `on()` instead, as of jQuery 1.7+:

```
$element.on('click', function() {
  $(this).text((i, t) => t == 'string1' ? 'string2' : 'string1');
});
```

Comment: +1 - Unlike the accepted answer, this method will work regardless of the text's initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Say your clickableElement is a button and you want to toggle the button's text/label:

```
$('#clickableElement').click(function() {
    var originalValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(originalValue == 'string1' ? 'string2' : 'string1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#togglep').on('click', function(){
  $(this).text(function(st1,st2){
    if (st2=='MARKO'){return 'POLO'};
    return 'MARKO'
  })
})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26187158)