# How to change the text inside an h1 element with jQuery by clicking on a button?

Tags: jquery

I have a button and when I click it, I want the text to change to a new text. When I click the button again, I want the text to change back. The text is dynamic, the text that needs to be displayed upon click is static.

Here is my attempt so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var titleOld = $(document).find('.head-bar .brand-title').text();
  $('.button').click(function() {
    titleOld.text('Cart');
  });
  titleOld.text(titleOld);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head-bar">
  <div class="brand col-6">
    <h1 class="brand-title"><?php echo $headerTitle ?></h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(document).find('.head-bar .brand-title').text();` is a string, not an object. You likely meant `var $titleElem = $(document).find('.head-bar .brand-title'), titleOld = $titleElem.text();`

Comment: To achieve the toggling between the values check the duplicate I marked, specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5575551/519413)

Comment: hi   you can try this one   $(document).ready(function () {
  var titleOld = $(document).find('.head-bar .brand-title').text();
  $('.button').click(function() {
      $('.brand-title').text('cart');
  });
  titleOld.text(titleOld);
})

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).find('.head-bar .brand-title').text();` is a string, not an object. You likely meant

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $titleElem = $(document).find('.head-bar .brand-title'), titleOld = $titleElem.text();
  $('.button').click(function() {
    var text = $titleElem.text() === titleOld ? "Cart" : titleOld;
    $titleElem.text(text);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head-bar">
  <div class="brand col-6">
    <h1 class="brand-title">headerTitle</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart">Button</i>
</div>
```